# Include third table in LEFT JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql, union, left-join

I have five mysql tables.
 **shops**

```
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | name         | address      |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | Shop1        | Street1      |
|  2 | Shop2        | Street2      |
|  3 | Shop3        | Street3      |
|  4 | Shop4        | Street4      |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

**fruits**

```
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | fruit        | price        |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | Bannana      | 2.5          |
|  2 | Apple        | 2.1          |
|  3 | Orange       | 1.8          |
|  4 | Plum         | 2.2          |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

**availability**

```
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | shop_id      | fruit_id     | 
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | 1            | 2            |
|  2 | 2            | 2            |
|  3 | 1            | 3            |
|  4 | 2            | 1            |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

**shop_activity**

```
+----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| id | shop_id      | user_id      | status       |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | 2            | 1            | 1            |
|  2 | 3            | 2            | 1            |
|  3 | 1            | 2            | 2            |
|  4 | 2            | 2            | 1            |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**users**

```
+----+--------------+
| id | name         | 
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Peter        |
|  2 | John         |
+----+--------------+
```

I have query

```
SELECT
    availability.shop_id,
    shops.name

FROM availability

LEFT JOIN shops
ON availability.shop_id=shops.id 

WHERE
fruit_id = 2
```

As a result I get name list of shops where fruit with id 2 (apple) is available.
What should I do so that I can include **shop_activity** table in query to get user's status if `users`.`id` = 1 beside proper shop. Something like this...

```
Shop1, NULL
Shop2, status: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT
    availability.shop_id,
    shops.name,
     shop_activity.status
FROM availability
LEFT JOIN shops
ON availability.shop_id=shops.id 
LEFT JOIN shop_activity
ON shop_activity.shop_id = availability.shop_id
   and shop_activity.user_id = 1
WHERE
fruit_id = 2
```

Comment: I have already tried something like that but it doesn't work. As a result I get only those shops which have apples AND where user's status exists. I want ALL shops which have apples.

Comment: Somehow I still get the same result.

Comment: @Goldie: Not sure, but does moving the `user_id` condition to the JOIN clause make a difference?

Comment: to understand why moving the condition to the join makes a difference:http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    availability.shop_id,
    shops.name

FROM shops 
LEFT JOIN availability ON availability.shop_id=shops.id 
LEFT JOIN shop_activity ON shop_activity .shop_id=shops.id
WHERE
fruit_id = 2
and users.id=1
```

try making shops as the first table in left join

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT shops.name, shop_activity.status
FROM shops
    INNER JOIN availability ON availability.shop_id = shops.id
        AND availability.fruit_id = 2
    LEFT JOIN shop_activity ON shops.shop_id = shop_activity.shop_id
        AND shop_activity.user_id = 1
```

This should give you a row for every shop with apples, but the status will show as null for shops where the user has no activity, otherwise shows the status of that user.